# Should there be multiple lines with wp_options in Wordpres php MyAdmin?

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a regular Wordpress site (not a multisite or network). In phpMyAdmin there are 22 lines for wp_options (each one has a difference beginning such as xxxx_wp_options) and each one is about 35MG each.

1. Is this supposed to be like this? If not, what can cause this?
2. Can I safely delete the duplicates?
3. I have the same duplicates for others such as wp_postmeta, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That does not sound normal. For a normal Wordpress install, there should only be 1 'table' for each category (wp_options, wp_postmeta, etc...).

Sounds like something went wrong with your install or perhaps you're trying to create multiple wp installs using the same database?

Comment: Agree and in case when you install WordPress as a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: I used a plugin to downgrade WP looking for a version that wouldn't clash with plugins. It seems like each time you try a different version your entire database is duplicated including the database for each plugin (not only WP core).